# C-style hexadecimals in Delphi - undocumented feature?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, hex

I noticed by chance that the following code

```
var
  I: Integer;

begin
  I:= StrToInt('0xAA');
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(I));  // shows 170 = $AA
end;
```

is OK in Delphi 2009. BTW the feature helped me to extract hexadecimal constants from C header file.

I wonder is it OK to use the feature or the feature is about to be "fixed" in future versions?

Comment: It is not a bug or something that needs to be fixed. It is just what `StrToInt()` has to do. Converting string to integer. And the string has to contain an integer value. No matter what format it is in.

Comment: No, @Azad, I can think of many formats for writing integers that `StrToInt` won't accept. Octal and binary come to mind.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy, sorry I didn't mean to say `StrToInt` has to accept anything you will write. I just want to say that if it works there is nothing wrong with this. And I don't believe it is going to be fixed :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a feature, and you can rely on it.  One of the philosophical changes that occurred in the evolution of Turbo Pascal into Delphi was the acknowledgment that Delphi lives in a C-dominated world and there was more to be gained by gracefully accepting or tolerating C-isms than ignoring them and forcing the Delphi developer to sort it out.  Interop with C++ Builder as mentioned by Rob was a factor, but so was the fact that Delphi was designed first for Windows, and Windows has a lot of C language artifacts in the Windows API.

I think the term "impedance mismatch" may apply here - it was simple enough to remove the impedance mismatch between Delphi hex handling and "Rest of World", so we did.

Comment: Always nice to see Mr. Thorpe on SO.

Answer (score 4):

Recall that the Delphi RTL is used by C++ Builder, too. The documentation doesn't go into detail about exactly what it means when it says `StrToInt`accepts "decimal or hexadecimal notation." You can safely expect `StrToInt` to continue to accept C-style numbers.

`Val` accepts the same input, as does `Read` (because they all end up calling `System._ValLong`).